How to correctly update firestore database in realtime with using bloc instead of stream builder
Hey i am building a social media app with bloc and bloc pattern data, domain and presentation layer
but i am stuck in the profile section
here is my profile bloc code
class ProfileBLoc extends Bloc<ProfileEvent, ProfileState> {
  final GetProfileDataUseCase getProfileDataUseCase;

  ProfileBLoc({
    required this.getProfileDataUseCase,
  }) : super(ProfileInitialState()) {
    on<ProfileLoadEvent>((event, emit) async {
      await emit.forEach(
        getProfileDataUseCase.call(event.uid),
        onData: (data) {
          print(data);
          final user =     UserModel.fromSnapshot(data);
                 return ProfileFoundState(user: user);
            },
          );
        });
      }
    }

code inside Remote Data Source
 @override
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getProfileData(String uid) {
    return firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).snapshots();
  }

Code inside Repository
@override
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getProfileData(String uid) =>
      profileRemoteDataSource.getProfileData(uid);

Use Case
class GetProfileDataUseCase {
  final ProfileRepository repository;

  GetProfileDataUseCase({required this.repository});

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> call(String uid) =>
      repository.getProfileData(uid);
}

I will get stream of doumentsnapshot from getProfileDataUseCase.call(event.uid) it will work perfectly but when i follow someone and the profile follow count was increase on this side but if the profile of that person which i follow is open in the other device it will show my profile on that device
why it was happening i can't understand
Note. When we work with streambuilder code working fine without any problem

It looks like your GetProfileDataUseCase is pulling incorrect data from Firebase. Can you share the code of your GetProfileUseCase?

i was successfully added the necessary code please check it

Okay, your code guarantees that it always fetches the correct data for a given uid. If the app is showing someone's else data then possible reasons could be:

invalid uid being passed to GetProfileUseCase
You have not used the BlocProvider right way


hey thanks for your reply
when i open profile page in different device and try to update other profile followers with follow button, i will try to update this in real time but when i click on follow it will update in real time but also change the profile data to other profile that i follow recently

in this code in the remote data source code the it will call with different uid why? my bloc automatically called with different uid how is this possible, without adding any event it will call anyone have any suggestion ?
